# rm -rf doesnt work with home tilde in java runtime

Tags: java, rm

This is my code to delete a folder , this below code wont delete the Downloads directory under home folder.

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class tester1{   
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("here going to delete stuff..!!");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf ~/Downloads/2");
        //deleteFile();
        System.out.println("Deleted ..!!");     }    
}
```

However if I give the complete home path, this works :

```
   import java.io.IOException;
    public class tester1{   
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("here going to delete stuff..!!");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf /home/rah/Downloads/2");
            //deleteFile();
            System.out.println("Deleted ..!!");
        }
        }
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong.?

Comment: can you add your error message to it?

Comment: Probably `~` is not expanded to user home. Try using `System.getProperty("user.home")` instead.

Answer (score 8):

The tilde (`~`) is expanded by the shell. When you call `exec` no shell is invoked, but rather the `rm` binary is called immediately and thus tildes are not expanded. Nor are wildcards and environment variables.

There are two solutions. Either replace tilde yourself like so:

```
String path = "~/Downloads/2".replace("~", System.getProperty("user.home"))
```

or call a shell by prefixing your command line like so

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c rm -rf ~/Downloads/2");
```

Comment: Prefixing is not enough, since `Runtime.exec(String)` is terminally broken and should never be used. The way to execute with a shell would be `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", "rm -rf ~/Downloads/2" });`

Comment: yeah, thats much better to avoid quoting problems and what not. Are you thinking about some other brokenness I don't know about?

Comment: It's required for the command to work at all. Without the array version, the command is equivalent to `sh -c rm`.

Answer (score 3):

The tilde expansion is done by the shell (eg. bash), however, you are running `rm` directly so there is no shell to interpret the `~`. I'd strongly recommend not relying on calling out to the shell for such functions - they are error-prone, have poor security properties and limit the operating systems on which your code can run.

However, if you really determined to use this particular method, you can do:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "rm -rf ~/Downloads/2" })`

Answer (score 1):

You're using shell syntax without a shell. Change the command to this:

```
new String[]{"sh", "-c", "rm -rf ~/Downloads/2"}
```

Comment: This won't work either, as the value for -c must be "one string", the java will see this as "sh" "-c" "rm" "-rf" "~/Downloads/2" instead of "sh" "-c" "rm -rf ~/Downloads/2", to fix it, the OP must use `exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c", "rm -rf ~/Downloads/2"});` instead. Just fix your answer

Comment: @morgano I've made the suggested change, as it's an improvement in the direction of being more specific, but I don't accept the claim that "this won't work either". I only stated what the command should be, and I did so correctly. I didn't say anything about how to split the command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an environment variable such as $HOME if using tilde is not necessary.


`String homeDir = System.getenv("HOME");
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf " + homeDir + "/Downloads/2");`